How to change the Liferay 7.3 homepage URL from 'localhost:8080' to 'localhost:8080/site?
I'm using Liferay version 7.3 u10 with Java 8. Currently, I access the Liferay homepage at 'localhost:8080' and I need to change this access to localhost:8080/site. How can I make this change ?
My setup is:
liferay 7.3 u10
Java 8
Blade v 6.0.1

This is Lifery's portal and it should help: Configuring Your Site’s Friendly URL
